# Getting a stream of events in a Bloc

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, flutter-bloc

I have two blocs - `BlocA` and `BlocB`. The latter adds events into the former.

```
class BlocA extends Bloc<BlocAEvent, BlocAState>{....}

class BlocB extends Bloc<BlocBEvent, BlocBState>{
  final BlocA blocA;

  ....

  Stream<BlocBState> mapEventToState(BlocBEvent event) {
    if(event is NotifyBlocA) blocA.add(FromBToAEvent());
  }
}
```

Everything is working fine. However, I need to write down a test that makes sure that when `BlocB` receives a `NotifyBlocA` event, `BlocA` does indeed receives a `FromBToAEvent` event. Is there a way to get the events stream of `BlocA` to check that? In the documentation, `_eventStream` is private. Is there a workaroud for this if no means are available at the moment?

NOTE: One could argue to look for `BlocA` state changes (ie `BlocA.stream`) and check whether correct states are emitted in response to `FromBToAEvent`. However, I need to write a unit test for `BlocB` without depending on the correctness of `BlocA`.